# Ninject.MVC5.Bootstrapper.Initializa throws " La séquence contient plusieurs éléments correspondants"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, ninject.web.mvc

I have a solution containing 4 projects:  Data,Domain,Service and Web. I installed Ninject.MVC5 Nuget package on Web project and Domain project then i deleted from the domain project.
I am using the NinjectWebCommon class in App_Start folder approch.

Versions:

1. Ninject"    version="3.2.2.0"
2. Ninject.MVC5"    version="3.2.1.0"
3. Ninject.Web.Common"    version="3.2.3.0"
4. Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost   version="3.2.3.0"
5. Unity"       version="3.5.1404.0"
6. Unity.Mvc    version="3.5.1404.0"
7. WebActivatorEx   version="2.0.6"

When I try to run the web projects, I get an InvalidOperationException saying "La séquence contient plusieurs éléments correspondants." when calling

bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);

Any ideas please??!!

Comment: the answer is : choise one of the refenreces DI : Unity or Inject,Inject.web... not both of them